# time library not working with PySimpleGUI

Tags: numpy, time, pysimplegui

here is the code:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as pg
import time as tm

import numpy as np

num = 0
layout = [
    [pg.Text('0', key='-txt')],
    [pg.Button('Start')],
]

timer_nums = np.arange(0.1, 1, .1)

win = pg.Window('Stopwatch', layout)

while True:
    e, v = win.read()
    if e == pg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if e == 'Start':
        tm.sleep(.14)
        for i in timer_nums:
            win['-txt'].update(round(i, 3))
            print(round(i, 3))
            tm.sleep(.1)

win.close()
```

So I'm trying to use the tm.sleep() to delay the count on a stopwatch. But each time i run the program the gui freezes, so i have the print function in so i can see the console telling me it's working right but the gui won't update txt until the for loop finishes. Which kinda defeats the purpose of the program lol. Please help

Comment: `sleep` stops the execution of the whole thread, so you can either handle the GUI on a different thread or, even better, just count time using the `time.time()`.

Comment: Call method `update` of element not update the GUI, loop to `win.read()` is required or call `win,refresh()` after your call to `element.update()`. GUI updated only after your `for` loop end to `win.read()`, so add one statement `win.refresh()` after the statement `win['-txt'].update(round(i, 3))` to update the GUI immediately.

Comment: Jason has it right.  Add a `window.refresh()` call after all `update` calls that you want to see in your window prior to the next `read()` call.  If you do not call `refresh`, then the changes will not appear until the next `read()` call